# Increasing delays in Java Flux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, delay, flux

I have a code where I can execute a piece of logic in loop with some delays in between using Flux. Something like this,

```
Flux.defer(() -> service.doSomething())
            .repeatWhen(v -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))
            .map(data -> mapper(data)) //map data
            .takeUntil(v -> shouldContinue(v)) //checks if the loop can be terminated
            .onErrorStop();
```

Now, I want to have incremental delays. Meaning, for the first 5 minutes, the delay can be 10 seconds between each execution. Then, for next 10 minutes, the delay can be 30 seconds. And, thereafter the delay can be a min between each execution.

How can I achieve this using Flux?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Meaning, for the first 5 minutes, the delay can be 10 seconds between each execution`. If I understand correctly, there are multiple executions in first 5 minutes, and they all delay 10s. Is it?

Comment: Do you want to consider the 5 minute time in to flux for increment? or just the delay time only?

Comment: Are 5 mins, 10 mins completion time for the flux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [`Flux.generate`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#generate-java.util.concurrent.Callable-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to create a custom sequence that emits items with the desired delays.
See also "[Difference Between `Flux.create` and `Flux.generate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216714/6309)".

```java
Flux<Object> flux = Flux.generate(
    () -> 0L,
    (state, sink) -> {
        sink.next(state);
        return state + 1;
    }
)
.delayUntil(state -> {
    long delay = 10; // default delay
    if (state < 30) { // first 5 minutes with 10 seconds delay
        delay = 10;
    } else if (state < 50) { // next 10 minutes with 30 seconds delay
        delay = 30;
    } else { // thereafter, 1 minute delay
        delay = 60;
    }
    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(delay));
})
.flatMap(state -> service.doSomething())
.map(data -> mapper(data))
.takeUntil(v -> shouldContinue(v))
.onErrorStop();
```

That would initialize the state to `0` and increments it with each iteration.
Depending on the state's value, which represents the number of elapsed periods, it applies different delays.

```
      ┌────────────┐         ┌─────────────────┐          ┌──────────────┐
      │   Flux     │         │ delayUntil with │          │  doSomething │
      │ generate   ├───────► │  custom delays  ├────────► │   Service    │
      └────────────┘         └─────────────────┘          └──────────────┘
            │                                                   │
            │                                                   │
            ▼                                                   ▼
      ┌────────────┐        ┌────────────────┐           ┌───────────────┐
      │   flatMap  │        │  takeUntil     │           │   onErrorStop │
      │  function  ├───────►│ shouldContinue ├─────────► │    method     │
      └────────────┘        └────────────────┘           └───────────────┘
```

Please note that in real-world applications, you might need to take into account the execution time of `service.doSomething()`. If it takes a significant amount of time, you might want to adjust the delays accordingly.

---

> What happens if the execution time of `doSomething()` is more than that of the delay? This might trigger `doSomething()` multiple times in parallel.

When the execution time of `doSomething()` is longer than the delay, the subsequent execution will not wait for the current one to complete, potentially causing concurrent executions indeed.

To prevent this, you could use a combination of `.concatMap()` which makes sure `doSomething()` is executed sequentially, along with a stateful map to calculate the delay based on when the last execution was started or completed.
See also "[What's the difference between `flatMap`, `flatMapSequential` and `concatMap` in Project Reactor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71972337/6309)"

> Also, if in case I want to start with a delay of 0 Seconds and then slowly increase the delay, how can I achieve that ?

You could then implement your feature, with a delay of 0 seconds and then slowly increase the delay:

```java
AtomicLong lastExecutionStart = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis());

Flux<Object> flux = Flux.generate(
    () -> 0L,
    (state, sink) -> {
        sink.next(state);
        return state + 1;
    }
)
.concatMap(state -> {
    long delay;
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = currentTime - lastExecutionStart.get();
    long executionTime = 0; // replace with actual execution time if known

    // Calculate the delay based on elapsed time since the start of the last execution
    if (elapsedTime <= 5 * 60 * 1000) { // first 5 minutes
        delay = Math.max(0, (10 - executionTime) * 1000); // 10 seconds delay, adjust for execution time
    } else if (elapsedTime <= 15 * 60 * 1000) { // next 10 minutes
        delay = Math.max(0, (30 - executionTime) * 1000); // 30 seconds delay, adjust for execution time
    } else { // thereafter
        delay = Math.max(0, (60 - executionTime) * 1000); // 60 seconds delay, adjust for execution time
    }

    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(delay))
        .then(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            lastExecutionStart.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
            return "doSomething";
        }))
        .flatMap(o -> service.doSomething());
})
.map(data -> mapper(data))
.takeUntil(v -> shouldContinue(v))
.onErrorStop();
```

`concatMap` makes sure `doSomething()` calls are made sequentially. The `lastExecutionStart` variable tracks when the last execution started. That variable is used to calculate the delay for the next execution.

The [`Mono.delay()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#delay-java.time.Duration-) is used with [`then()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-) to wait for the calculated delay before starting the next execution.
After the delay, `doSomething()` is called and the `lastExecutionStart` timestamp is updated.

That pattern makes sure:

- `doSomething()` is not executed concurrently.
- The delay before the next `doSomething()` execution takes into account the actual execution time.
- The initial delay can be 0, and then increment based on the logic you provide.

```bash
        ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────┐
        │                    Flux                      │
        └──────────────────────────────────────────────┘
                          │
            ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
            │     Generate (state)      │
            └─────────────┬─────────────┘
                          │
            ┌─────────────▼─────────────┐
            │   Calculate Next Delay    │ <────┐
            └─────────────┬─────────────┘      │
                          │                    │
         ┌────────────────▼─────────────────┐  │
         │            Mono.delay            │  │
         └────────────────┬─────────────────┘  │
                          │                    │
         ┌────────────────▼──────────────────┐ │
         │  Set lastExecutionStart Timestamp │ │
         └────────────────┬──────────────────┘ │
                          │                    │
            ┌─────────────▼─────────────┐      │
            │       service.doSomething │      │
            └─────────────┬─────────────┘      │
                          │                    │
            ┌─────────────▼─────────────┐      │
            │            map            │      │
            └─────────────┬─────────────┘      │
                          │                    │
            ┌─────────────▼─────────────┐      │
            │         takeUntil         │      │
            └─────────────┬─────────────┘      │
                          │                    │
            ┌─────────────▼─────────────┐      │
            │         onErrorStop       │      │
            └─────────────┬─────────────┘      │
                          │                    │
                          └────────────────────┘
```

---

> I noticed that if `dataProvider.fetchData()` returns a `Flux`, I was getting an error `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <V> concatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Publisher<? extends V>>)`.
> But it works fine if `Mono` was returned.  So I had to use a `flatMapMany` instead of `flatMap`.
>
> But is there a way to handle if `service.doSomething()` can return either a `Flux` or a `Mono`?
>
> I was thinking of writing this as a generic service. Hence would like to see if this can handle data of type `Flux<T>` , `Mono<T>` and even of type `T`.

To handle a service method that can return a `Flux<T>`, `Mono<T>`, or `T`, you will need to adapt the method call within your reactive pipeline to cater to these different reactive types. One approach is to use `flatMapMany` indeed, to handle both `Mono` and `Flux` since `Mono` can be converted to a `Flux`, but not vice versa.

```java
AtomicLong lastExecutionStart = new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis());

Flux<Object> flux = Flux.generate(
    () -> 0L,
    (state, sink) -> {
        sink.next(state);
        return state + 1;
    }
)
.concatMap(state -> {
    long delay;
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = currentTime - lastExecutionStart.get();
    long executionTime = 0; // replace with actual execution time if known

    // Calculate the delay based on elapsed time since the start of the last execution
    if (elapsedTime <= 5 * 60 * 1000) { // first 5 minutes
        delay = Math.max(0, (10 - executionTime) * 1000); // 10 seconds delay, adjust for execution time
    } else if (elapsedTime <= 15 * 60 * 1000) { // next 10 minutes
        delay = Math.max(0, (30 - executionTime) * 1000); // 30 seconds delay, adjust for execution time
    } else { // thereafter
        delay = Math.max(0, (60 - executionTime) * 1000); // 60 seconds delay, adjust for execution time
    }

    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(delay))
        .then(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            lastExecutionStart.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
            return "doSomething";
        }))
        // Use flatMapMany to handle both Mono and Flux from doSomething()
        .flatMapMany(o -> Flux.from(service.doSomething()));
})
.map(data -> mapper(data))
.takeUntil(v -> shouldContinue(v))
.onErrorStop();
```

By using `flatMapMany`, you can make sure the service call can return a `Flux` or be a `Mono` which will be converted to a `Flux`. For handling a synchronous type `T`, you would typically wrap it with `Mono.just()` or `Flux.just()` depending on whether you want a single result or a stream of results.

To truly make your service generic, you would have to make sure the `doSomething()` method signature is appropriately designed to return a `Publisher<T>`, which both `Mono` and `Flux` implement. That will allow you to abstract away the differences between these types within the service method itself.

For handling synchronous values (`T`), you would need to create a reactive wrapper within the service method, something like this:

```java
public Publisher<T> doSomething() {
    T result = ...; // Your synchronous logic here
    return Mono.just(result); // or Flux.just(result) if it makes sense to return a stream
}
```

That way, you can use the same `flatMapMany` method in your reactive pipeline to handle all types of return values from `doSomething()`.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Few follow up thoughts. what happens if the execution time of `doSomething()` is more than that of the delay? This might trigger `doSomething()` multiple times in parallel. Also, if in case i want to start with a delay of 0 Seconds and then slowly increase the delay, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Good questions. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the update and it works quite well for my requirement. However, I noticed that if `dataProvider.fetchData()` returns a Flux, I was getting an error `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <V> concatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Publisher<? extends V>>)`. But it works fine if Mono was returned. So had to use a `flatMapMany` instead of `flatMap`. But is there a way to handle if `service.doSomething()` can return either a Flux or a Mono ?

Comment: I was thinking of writing this as a generic service. Hence would like to see if this can handle data of type Flux<T> , Mono<T> and even of type T.

Comment: @PraveenKumar True, I have edited the answer to use `flatMapMany`, and to be generic.

Comment: Great, works as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

While Project Reactor is a great tool, it's important to keep in mind that not all tasks need to be solved via Project Reactor. In my opinion, sometimes using pure Java might be a less complex and better fit even if Project Reactor is the main tool in your app stack. But since I don't know your real case I will share both versions.

Option 1: Less Reactor, more pure Java.

```java
public class ScheduledTask {
    private final Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newSingle("custom-scheduled-task");
    private final Instant startTime = Instant.now();

    {
        scheduler.schedule(this::task); // if you don't want delay on start 
        //scheduler.schedule(this::task, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // if you want delay on start
    }

    private void task() {
        System.out.println("do something"); // you can inject your service to the class and execute needed method here

        if (shouldContinue()) {
            scheduler.schedule(this::task, calculateDelaySec(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldContinue() {
        return true; // put your custom logic here
    }

    private long calculateDelaySec() {
        var minutesSpentSinceStart = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now()).toMinutes();

        if (minutesSpentSinceStart < 5) return 10;
        if (minutesSpentSinceStart < 15) return 30;

        return 60;
    }
}
```

Option 2: Reactor-way

This approach is pretty close to the @VonC recommendation, I've modified the `generate` method to make it more suitable according to requirements.

```java
public class ScheduledTask2 {

    private record FluxArgs(Instant startTime, Boolean calculateDelay) {}

    private static Flux<String> task() {
        return Flux.<Duration, FluxArgs>generate(
                // use start time as initial value and boolean marker to skip start delay
                () -> new FluxArgs(Instant.now(), false),
                (args, sink) -> {
                    if (args.calculateDelay) {
                        sink.next(Duration.ofSeconds(calculateDelaySec(args.startTime)));
                    } else {
                        sink.next(Duration.ZERO);
                    }
                    // pass start time as argument for next iteration and calculateDelay:true to calculate correct delay
                    return new FluxArgs(args.startTime, true);
                }
            )
            .delayUntil(Mono::delay)
            .concatMap(ignore -> doSomething()) // concatMap is used to make sure that doSomething is not executed in parallel
            .takeUntil(ScheduledTask2::shouldStop);
    }

    private static long calculateDelaySec(Instant startTime) {
        var minutesSpentSinceStart = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now()).toMinutes();

        if (minutesSpentSinceStart < 5) return 10;
        if (minutesSpentSinceStart < 15) return 30;

        return 60;
    }

    private static Mono<String> doSomething() {
        return Mono.just("");
    }

    private static boolean shouldStop(String val) {
        return true; // put your custom logic here
    }
}
```

Option 3: Mix.

You can use this option if you need to have the results of your task execution as a Flux to propagate them further. As for me, this option looks less complex than option 2 but allows you to utilize results as a Flux stream.

Please remember that depending on your needs, you can use different `Sinks` APIs like `multicast()` or `unicast()` here.

```java
public class ScheduledTask3 {

    private final Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newSingle("custom-scheduled-task");
    private final Instant startTime = Instant.now();
    private final Sinks.Many<String> sink = Sinks.many().replay().all();

    {
        scheduler.schedule(this::task); // if you don't want delay on start 
        //scheduler.schedule(this::task, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // if you want delay on start
    }

    public Flux<String> taskResults() {
        return sink.asFlux();
    }

    private void task() {
        var result = doSomething();
        sink.tryEmitNext(result);

        if (shouldContinue()) {
            scheduler.schedule(this::task, calculateDelaySec(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }

    private String doSomething() {
        return "";
    }

    private boolean shouldContinue() {
        return true; // put your custom logic here
    }

    private long calculateDelaySec() {
        var minutesSpentSinceStart = Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now()).toMinutes();

        if (minutesSpentSinceStart < 5) return 10;
        if (minutesSpentSinceStart < 15) return 30;

        return 60;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Similar to @VonC recommendation, few follow up thoughts. what happens if the execution time of `doSomething()` is more than that of the delay? This might trigger `doSomething()` multiple times in parallel. Also, if in case i want to start with a delay of 0 Seconds and then slowly increase the delay, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar for "Option 1" and "Option 3": doSomething() will not be triggered in parallel. To remove the initial delay on start, you can remove the delay in `schedule` method in the initializer block. As for "Option 2" it is possible that `doSomething()` can run in parallel, to fix this you need to replace `flatMap` with `concatMap`. As for the initial delay - to remove it you need to add the additional marker to the `generate` method.  I've updated all options in my original post so they now match these requirements. Please check and let me know if you have questions or need help.